# How to get a subset of `keyof T` whose value, T[K] are callable functions in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to filter `keyof T` based on type of `T[keyof T]`

It should work like this:

```
type KeyOfType<T, U> = ...

KeyOfType<{a: 1, b: '', c: 0, d: () => 1}, number> === 'a' | 'c'

KeyOfType<{a: 1, b: '', c: 0: d: () => 1}, string> === 'b'

KeyOfType<{a: 1, b: '', c: 0: d: () => 1}, Function> === 'd'
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the `as` clause of a mapped type to filter the keys of a type:

```
type KeyOfType<T, V> = keyof {
    [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V? P: never]: any
}
```

The `as` clause of a mapped type allows us to manipulate the name of the key. If the key is mapped to `never` the key gets removed from the resulting type. You can find more info in this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)

### Pre TS 4.1

This version still works in post 4.1, just the other way is easier to read.

You can do this using conditional and mapped types

```
type KeyOfType<T, U> = {[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends U ? P: never}[keyof T]
```

Let's break things down a little bit.

We can start with a mapped type, that has the same properties of the same type as the original `T`, this a simple standard mapped type:

```
type KeyOfType<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] } // New Type same as the original
```

`T[P]` is a type query and means the type of the key `P` in type `T`. We can change this to just `P`, meaning that the type of the new property is the same as it's name:

```
type KeyOfType<T> = { [P in keyof T]: P }
// So
KeyOfType<{ a: number, b: string }> == { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
```

We can add a type query to this type to again get all the keys of the type. Generally a construct `T[keyof T]` gets all the property types of a type. Applying this to our mapped type which has the property types the same as the key names we basically get back to `keyof T`:

```
type KeyOfType<T> = { [P in keyof T]: P }[keyof T]
// So
KeyOfType<{ a: number, b: string }> ==  'a'|'b'
```

Now we can add a conditional type to o not always select `P`. Since `A | never ==  A` we can set the type of the property in the mapped type to never if the type of the original property (`T[P]`) does not meet a certain constraint.

To express the constraint we add an extra generic parameter `U` and we use a conditional type which has the form `T extends U ? TypeIfTrue: TYpeIfFalse`. Putting it together we get:

```
type KeyOfType<T, U> = {[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends U ? P: never}[keyof T]
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, but can u explain `{...}[keyof T]` part? How does [keyof T] works?

Comment: @Joon sorry was on my lunch break, hope the explanation clears it up :)

Comment: Thanks for great explanation! I got it now!

Comment: How about value type of an item in object?

Comment: Oh nvm, I found how can I extract value, just: Pick<typeof obj, 'whatever_string'>

Answer (score 2):

awesome explanation!!

I would also add that you can set a default type to `U` to be any key of `T` like so:

```
type Keys<T> = {[P in keyof T]: T[P]}[typeof P]

type KeyOfType<T, U = Keys<T>> = {[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends U ? P : never}[keyof T]
```

I add `U = Keys<T>` to the generic definition of `KeyOfType`

Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PickByValue` from the `utility-types` library.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/utility-types#pickbyvaluet-valuetype

```
import { PickByValue } from 'utility-types';

class MyClass {
  propertyOne = 'one';
  propertyTwo = 'two';
  methodOne() {
    console.log('I am a method');
  }
  methodTwo() {
    console.log('I am a method');
  }
}

type methods = keyof PickByValue<MyClass, Function> // 'methodOne' | 'methodTwo'
```

In my example `keyof PickByValue<MyClass, () => void>` works as well if you want to avoid using the `Function` type.