# How to filter a parent type in order to pick the children of a given type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, mapped-types

## What I need

I have an undetermined number of objects in a key-value parent object. Each child has a property `namespaced` of type `boolean`:

```
const obj1 = {
  namespaced: true,
  a() {}
} as const

const obj2 = {
  namespaced: false,
  b() {}
} as const

const parentObj = {
  obj1,
  obj2
} as const
```

Is it possible to make a mapped type which contains only objects with `namespaced` set to `true` (and the same with `false`)?

## What I tried

```
interface ParentObj {
  [name: string]: Obj
}

interface Obj {
  namespaced: boolean
}

type FilterNamespaced<P extends ParentObj> = {
  [O in keyof P]: P[O] extends { namespaced: true } ? P[O] : never
}

type FilterNotNamespaced<P extends ParentObj> = {
  [O in keyof P]: P[O] extends { namespaced: false } ? P[O] : never
}

type F1 = FilterNamespaced<typeof parentObj>

type F2 = FilterNotNamespaced<typeof parentObj>
```

It is almost done but `F1` still contains a key `obj2` of type never, and `F2` contains a key `obj1` too. I would like to have the same thing but without these keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but you need an extra level of indirection. You need to filter the keys first and then pick them from the original type. Using something like `KeyOfType` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419176/how-to-get-a-subset-of-keyof-t-whose-value-tk-are-callable-functions-in-typ) will get you to where you want:

```
type KeyOfType<T, U> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends U ? P : never }[keyof T]

type FilterNamespaced<P extends ParentObj> = Pick<P, KeyOfType<P, { namespaced: true }>>

type FilterNotNamespaced<P extends ParentObj> = Pick<P, KeyOfType<P, { namespaced: false }>>
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=93&pln=9&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApyhcB5ARgK2QG8AoZZAbRDgFsIAuZAZzClAHMBdRvfEgXxIlQkWIhS9iZZNTpMADuIAmjXAHs1AGwhwQAoSTABPeSgDSEI9hgAVExAA8NgDTIAqgD5kAXmKVUyKDIANaWajDINtyRFKicyBAAHpAgSkzuyAD8aMiMIBAAbtDI-BShRuGRnELGpsgAYsCaogBytBAKyg4BSSlpaBhYYLxevqjACMHdrhZWtvbTfrIdikgqyKwArij8Hh419g1NrWpgbXKrEErdCclY-eiYOASjaBNTqDOW1nami0QydqdNaMeCaJg7PZCBBqEAsZBqAgARh8UnIy2BV0YWwgzmkcAAFABKYiCfjIODpGFwsDQ2HwxH4ABMqNI6KBl3WYIhePIuGJpIEFKp9NpJGp8MUT2GBFZ0kZSN5CIITKFlOQErFtRQ9RRvkazWg5xWXW1lSlQxGBzq9RZ+uORtOxsx1zNEQtz3wHiAA)