# Generic type holding a method of class with parameters of this method

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I wanted to create a generic type that will hold a method that exists on a clas with parameters of this method, but when I am providing the class instance to the generic I get [never, never].

I would use it this type inside a class so I provide a simplified example of potential usage

Example usage inside a class

```
type AnyClass = { new (...arg0: any): any }

type SingeTask<V extends InstanceType<AnyClass>> = [
  Extract<keyof V, (...arg0: any) => any>,
  Parameters<Extract<keyof V, (...arg0: any) => any>>
]

type Task<V extends InstanceType<AnyClass>> = {
  task: SingeTask<V>
  resolve: (value?: unknown) => void
  reject: (reason: any) => void
}

class Queue<T extends AnyClass> {
  instances: InstanceType<T>[] = []
  queue: Task<T>[] = []
  object: T

  constructor(object: T) {
    this.object = object
  }

  addInstance( number:number) {
      for (i; i < number; i++) {
        this.instances.push(new this.object())
  }

  

  runTasksInQueue(
    instance: InstanceType<T>,
    { task, reject, resolve }: Task<T>
  ) {
    try {
      const respone = Reflect.apply(instance, ...task)
      resolve(respone)
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error)
    } finally {
      const task = this.queue.pop()
      if (task) {
        this.runTasksInQueue(instance, task)
      } else {
        this.instances.push(instance)
      }
    }
  }

  addTaskToQueue(task: SingeTask<T>) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const instance = this.instances.pop()
      if (instance) {
        this.runTasksInQueue(instance, { task, resolve, reject })
      } else {
        this.queue.push({ task, resolve, reject })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Usage of the class Queue

```
class mockClass {
  sth?: number
  constructor(n?: number) {
    this.sth = n
  }
  getNumber(n: number) {
    return n
  }
}

const instanceQueue = new queue(mockClass)
instanceQueue.addInstance(5)
instanceQueue.addTaskToQueue() // Here I get error [never,never] but I would expect to be able to pass [getNumber,(number e.g - 10)] and receive 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your code is mostly correct in intent it has two issues to begin with:

1. `V extends InstanceType<AnyClass>` does not mean `V` will be the instance type of whatever is passed in, it just means `V` must extend whatever is the instance type of `AnyClass` is, which is `any`. So this reduces to `V extends any`. So when you get `SingeTask<typeof mockClass>` in your code, `V` will be `typeof mockClass` not the instance type of `mockClass`. You need to remove the constraint and use `InstanceType<V>` anywhere you need the instance type
2. `Extract<keyof V, (...arg0: any) => any>` will not filter the keys of `V` to only those that have a specific value. `Extract` will take out of a union, some the types that extend the second parameter. So for example `Extract<"a" | "b", "a">` will be `"a"`. Or more usefully `Extract<Circle | Rectangle, { type: "circle" }>` will be circle ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLCggNi5BvAKGWTAE8AHCALmQCIENsJaAaI5KOAE2AFcBnGiF4BbAEbQCAXwIFQkWIhQAlCAjBwQAcxz52ZSjVpQ1YVuwDuwLmAAWQ0RKjtbEYFttgH4yTIIGVZABeZABRAA8wTnUAHnRMXQAfZFV1TR0IFnwSCmo6BgTmZCkAPiA)). To get keys by a specific type you need something like the type `KeyOfType` you see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419176/how-to-get-a-subset-of-keyof-t-whose-value-tk-are-callable-functions-in-typ) answer (I will just use `KeyOfType`, you can read the expiations in the referenced answer as to how it works)

Putting these two observation together we get the first usable iteration of `SingleTask`:

```
type KeyOfType<T, U> = {[P in keyof T]-?: T[P] extends U ? P: never}[keyof T]
type ValuesOfType<T, U> = {[P in keyof T]-?: T[P] extends U ? T[P]: never}[keyof T]
// Alternate version of ValuesOfType
// type ValuesOfType<T, U> = Extract<T[keyof T], U>

type SingeTask<V extends AnyClass> = [
  KeyOfType<InstanceType<V>, (...arg0: any) => any>,
  Parameters<ValuesOfType<InstanceType<V>, (...arg0: any) => any>>
]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAwgGwIYGd1QLxQN5RwQDuUAFAHRWoBOA5gAwBcUqCAlC2yFAL4BQ-UJCgBpCCADyAMwAq4CAB5ZAGigBVAHw58AbQAKUAJZwoAawkB7aVFkBdALQB+FrIN2oEAB7AIcACZY6lBOUPosRABuEDS8uhYg1rZ2QgpQAGqoyACuEOgy8pDKalo6eAbGpglJ9s6u7p4+foEaIbbuERDRsfFWNvaCwtAAyiZ0ELIYZorpjb4BWPBIaJjauLr8UGISBQqKAJJw6MBsAMYTe+maapTU9MysHDja3NebYbSoALYQvjToMyyuXycj2h2OZwuRSuNyoFFojC4T2wLwQmk0-BSgzSXlxOlGcHGk3Q0yGSS+llOZhQGHQGNSImJ01m3nmLXBJzg50KSiWNNWa3w7xOJJYBKJUxmGK2NDylmQ0RYZEiQIgLig2TgZjglmIcHYzygkUsRn871lACsIKdgErZRhLHAkSADSijSazQJ+KcVlgAIq5XLKObNRYIfl0oVbEwQrl5FgcyE85SaXQedYpLYAR0DEFcktkqfTUDT70sACMrTbXIItqdHccaNkbZYaGQK1XbbYDXh3ltgAALIzoCgd63AHRjm3vL1bVD+fyJuNkQjZL7lmJMOBrjc0Ht9rZQaSt8jIX7GHQMADcF8Uq-XMRvRgA1M-94eP1BB8OKDHOecRzAbJ0AHMgiFIb8RynYAyHYdgDy2ARENrKAUKbOAmXQQ4AwgXIyAPP9IQTI5-yhJRCxUA8CBFMw1Etcc6LlBVoF4fMSRTd530PYAaB4XtPygesSKgWV0DAR1oFwAAlCBpDPG14TAMBkBAMhCLjNQ4Ro+CBNE+VojIUTxKIHTD14QTUGAU4B3IGIaFbLiP3om0yDshyD3M6QTCyFSo0-ITji-KYdEgigc1wiAKHEsBYIQ4wbDIbS-IE0L0Mw7DczUkjITUbS4vMiBkHQaB+IEr8hxHdSAKi4DQKqiBTI-JCzJnFD538JlZEsHC8JosUxgmAtNEckTfmyGhTHAsJ7K+YcIDIQymOiRjO1dbRSo-AKJ3qkKKt-bK40AywYsaw8jAS+qRo-VLNXSuAevm+q1GoqZGPQfSIBW8c+FOxDPCKkq4v7PbwtyGqQLIF6STej6vptH78o80yBC9H1aSgCkqQjPygPLZAjFOI8jEK-wWEbMYdAAIkp95xmAAA5HcYjAiImb3fBRuAcbJr4WnfmGHixjIdAycFwke057moCwFHBC2ypY3OB6dCmh6yEx6lfXg+qHvhBcl3OMgAFZtYOpXcz1jqpi6tXdEpunGYfGhKbUXQAEY7DsA0AHpvagCT713YwsEsMwoEAUHJ+B1i32s67rMrtumBZoMYXZLSmYEpz2fb9gPycJYP-bDyPo4iy249t+3+bFug07tzO1EpgAhLOvagX3CEsCdQ4jqOzYgXXY+t+OIrIO2vJJuvs-bv2dSJkmsBL-vB4XCuE6r4Bk9T12Pbbjv6a7ouoCAA)

Testing it out looks good at first :

```
class mockClass {
  public field: string = ""
  getNumber(n: number) { return n }
  getString(s: string) { return s }
}

const instanceQueue = new Queue(mockClass)
instanceQueue.addInstance(5)
instanceQueue.addTaskToQueue(["getNumber", [1]]) // one number is ok ✅
instanceQueue.addTaskToQueue(["getString", ["A"]]) // one string is ok ✅
instanceQueue.addTaskToQueue(["getString", ["A", "B"]]) // not ok ✅
instanceQueue.addTaskToQueue(["field", []]) // no fields ✅
```

But then we find a subtle issue, this is valid:

```
instanceQueue.addTaskToQueue(["getString", [1]]) // Allowed
```

The issue is that there is no relation between the first member of the tuple, and the second. Applied to mock class `SingeTask` results in the type `["getNumber" | "getString", [number] | [string]]`. While this does provide some safety, it does mean we ca mix the parameters of `getNumber` with the name of `getString`.

The solution to this is to generate a union of tuples instead of a tuple with union members as above. Basically we want `["getNumber", [number]] | ["getString", [string]]`.

We can apply the same ideas as `KeyOfType` and get the union of tuples containing key names and parameters instead of just key names:

```
type SingeTask<V extends AnyClass> = {
  [P in keyof InstanceType<V>]-?: InstanceType<V>[P] extends (...a: any) => any ? [P, Parameters<InstanceType<V>[P]>]: never
}[keyof InstanceType<V>]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAwgGwIYGd1QLxQN5RwQDuUAFAHRWoBOA5gAwBcUqCAlC2yFAL4BQ-UJCgBpCCADyAMwAq4CAB5ZAGigBVAHw58AbQAKUAJZwoAawkB7aVFkBdALQB+FrIN2oEAB7AIcACZY6lBOUPosRABuEDS8uhYg1rZ2QgpQAGqoyACuEOgy8pDKalo6eAbGpglJ9s6u7p4+foEaIbbuERDRsfFWNvaCwtAAyiZ0ELIYZorpjb4BWPBIaJjauHj8UFAVJuZ9UACScOjAbADGEwozmo4uh8encBeFSumaDd7zLZTUXBw42m4bQMan0tFQAFsIL4aOhFEcTudLkU3u4bp1uvw4tUbAjHs8rm8UoM0l4yTpRnBxpN0NMhkkIZYzmYUBh0JoSSIadNZp9mosEKzVmVNlBTrSWJTqVNrqKaHlLMhoiwyJEsrk7tk4GY4JZiHB2ACoJFLEZ-HKIAArCBnYAq+UYSxwP4gQ3YbQms1YwRnFZYACKuVyyjm-Nggr92g2WxMiKeeRYeKRL2U7w8uF0KS2AEcgxBXDLZGmdJnRZYAEbW22uQRbM5Ok40bK2yw0MgVqt22yG6NbMUACyM6AoHZtwB0o9tooEotQ-n8SfjZEI2Qh5ZiTDgq-XNB7or7UGkrfIyGhxh0DAA3OfFCu1zFr0YANRPvcHg-AQfD2P4vIUMDZOg-ZkEQpCfkOI6VmOZDsOw+59gIWwzlstZQE2cDcugRyBhAuRkPBP5IomDzJlcRYqPBBDimYajyp2tEKkq0C8AWtKpqKb59sANA8L2B71g8aF5GATrQLgABKEDSKetoUKgYBgMgIBkIR8ZqFQFDUXB75CegirRGQ8roCJRDaQhUBnKgwBnP25AxDQracQedHQfZjnwbwh4mFkSn4PBdYNuO1E6OBw65rhED-pYYAwf5xg2GQWl+TpWyhRQ6GYdheYqSRalilMZkHp5EDIOg0B8e+aWqRcw4AUBOVxhchUIR506oXO-jcrIlg4Xh1GSmMEyFpoTlCcA2Q0KYoFhA5EJDhAZCGYx0QMZ2bpRnFAknJUjViQOEHVX+Ikxc1MYJYdo0fl+6VaplcC9Qth1qFRUwMXpTGrWOfCnXwnileVcWpdd4W5P+gHAS9tJvfpECfba31xYhCFmQIM6+myUCMsyQpYL2AHlsgRhnF5JX+CwjZjDoABEVOiuMwAAHLbjEIERMzu74GNE1TXwdPQsM3FjGQ6Dk4LVI9lzk1QFgqM+oFO2-g9OjTQ9ZBYyyfpwYdD1yfOi4XGQACsWu5RcOsdV1PXZboVP00z940FTai6AAjHYdiGgA9J7UCiXeO7GFglhmFAgCg5Pw2t5rrnVTN1qs2-TAs0GMTvbFTMBU+7Xs+37FNUoHvsh+HkcRdHlvx7b-Ni3Qqc2xnahUwAQpnHtQN7hCWOOwdhxHpsQOb87l9bVPSEYpO11nbc+7qJPIC0xd9wPMe0nHw+J9Xtdu637cAKI0A5NBh0AA)

With this new version we can't mix parameter of one function with the name of another function

```
instanceQueue.addTaskToQueue(["getString", [1]]) // Error ✅
```