# Define type constraint with the keys of an interface whose type is specific

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let me clear the question. I have an interface whose keys are tag names and the type of each key is the corresponding custom element class.

```
// custom element class
class View extends HTMLElement { ... }
abstract class ScrollLayout extends View { ... }
class ListView extends ScrollLayout { ... }
class GridView extends ScrollLayout { ... }

// Tag to Class
interface Tag2Class {
    "p-view": View;
    "p-list-view": ListView;
    "p-grid-view": GridView;
}
```

Now, I want to define another interface that has a key named `layout` whose type is the key of `Tag2Class` typed `ScrollLayout`

```
interface Attrs {
    layout?: ??? // I want the type to be "p-list-view" | "p-grid-view" | undefined
}
```

Is there a way to implement this? I tried Record<>

```
interface Attrs {
    layout?: keyof Record<keyof Tag2Class, ScrollLayout>;
}
```

But strangely, the type of `layout` also contains `"p-view"`. I don't understand why the result came out like that because the Record type above would return the type `{ [P in keyof Tag2Class]: ScrollLayout }`, and the keyof this would be only `"p-list-view" | "p-grid-view"`.

Comment: Why do you think `keyof Tag2Class` should not include p-view?  It's one of the attributes of that interface.

Comment: @sam256 I think so because `Record` itself constrains the type of `[P in keyof Tag2Class]` to be `ScrollLayout`. And `View` is not `ScrollLayout`.

Comment: Record does not constrain.  The two parameters to it are independent.  So you are just defining a type with all the keys of Tag2Class and each having a type of ScrollLayout.  That said, I think I understand your question--you want a type that only includes attribute names for types that extend ScrollLayout.  Is that right?

Comment: @sam256 Yeah! Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `KeyOfType` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419176/how-to-get-a-subset-of-keyof-t-whose-value-tk-are-callable-functions-in-typ) to filter keys of a specific type:

```
type KeyOfType<T, U> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends U ? P : never }[keyof T]

interface Attrs {
    layout?: KeyOfType<Tag2Class, ScrollLayout> //  "p-list-view" | "p-grid-view" | undefined
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=14&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqCWBTA7tRAPALogdgExgAkAVAWQBkBRERAW102gG9oA3ALmjBwE9oBfAFBgARhEwAnMMEahIMAMrAJAexAhyYHioCujDNnwwEKZtAidufIXKjRy8cSdQHcBaEtXrN2vWZCWvAKCtjAA4hLweM5oWG6KymoaWrqMLADmgdaCOYIA9HnQxGDp0Jgq0ADC4FCC8DjYEgBm0ohFJQBM1fLMgtD90ABEAA4AtKxIyIOczgDcfQMjoyCOmOOT0-arcwv9S+mReOsomxFRO0KCmDzDbQDSiDwA8k3EN4gAPMQANNAAqgA+aAAXjMAG0AArQerQADWjxUTSKAF1OMRIcjYoZ3H9oAB+aBQzg4RCsRASARg+HaJHEZE5eqNFrANoAQUwkhgTF20HAvkweM4D2er3eX063Sgv08SR8qSBBT2YxW4mOU2gAB8hmMDlE1YNNdAdPhEE16og8IJ+EA)

Comment: This is an insane approach. I would never be able to come up with this on my own :(. Thank you so much! :)