# Get all keys of specific type from object in typescript

Tags: typescript

Title says it all, but an example is best.

```typescript
interface A {
  key1: string
  key2: string
  key3: number
}

type KeysOfType<O, T> = keyof {
  [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends T ? O[K] : never
}

function test<O,T>(obj: O, key: KeysOfType<O,T>) {
  obj[key] // should only be of type T
}

const aa: A = {
  key1: "1",
  key2: "2",
  key3: 3
}

test<A,string>(aa, "key1") // should be allowed, because key1 should be a string
test<A,string>(aa, "key3") // should NOT be allowed (but is), because key3 should be a number
```

However, this allows any `keyof` the interface `A`. (i.e., both calls above are valid).

Is it possible to do this with typescript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a subset of \`keyof T\` whose value, T\[K\] are callable functions in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419176/how-to-get-a-subset-of-keyof-t-whose-value-tk-are-callable-functions-in-typ)

Comment: In short yes, your answer is correct. However I was hoping for the typing to work inside the function as well (i.e., obj[key] would be inferred as type T), but it does not. I can see how this isn't possible or supported yet as it's a bit complex. The type system would need to know that `key` was only going to pull out values from `obj` of type `T`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change your KeysofType definition to:

```
type KeysOfType<O, T> = {
  [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends T ? K : never
}[keyof O]
```

This is explained in detail in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419176/how-to-get-a-subset-of-keyof-t-whose-value-tk-are-callable-functions-in-typ).