# TypeScript function return a value of a key which has a special type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have an object like this

```
const person = {
    name: 'Amir',
    age: 25,
    favoriteFruits: ['Apple', 'Orange']
};
```

I need a function to accept a key which its value is an array.

Here the second argument in IDE should just suggest the `favoriteFruits` key:

```
get(person, '');
```

I tried to make such function but it accepts all of the keys

```
function get<T, Key extends keyof T>(container: T, key: Key) {
    return container[key];
}
```

Comment: You have a typo at your first argument (`perosn`). After fixing that your function works fine for me.

Comment: @Behemoth Edited. But the function suggest all of the keys. I need to just accept `favoriteFruits`, not anything else.

Comment: Do you want to accept the string (key) `"favoriteFruits"` or the actual content? If you just want the key then do something like `type Favorite = "favoriteFruits"` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the following helper type:

```
type RemoveNonArrayKeys<T> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends unknown[] ? K : never]: T[K];
}
```

It will filter the keys that are not arrays, after that you only need to redefine your function `get` as:

```
function get<T>(container: T, key: RemoveNonArrayKeys<T>) {
    return container[key];
}
```

The whole example with some extra test:

```
const person = {
    name: 'Amir',
    age: 25,
    favoriteFruits: ['Apple', 'Orange'],
    // Test
    favoriteNumbers: [1, 2, 3]
};

type RemoveNonArrayKeys<T> = keyof{
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends unknown[] ? K : never]: T[K];
}

type onlyArrayPersonKeys = RemoveNonArrayKeys<typeof person>;
//   ^?   "favoriteFruits" | "favoriteNumbers"

function get<T>(container: T, key: RemoveNonArrayKeys<T>) {
    return container[key];
}

get(person, 'favoriteFruits');
get(person, 'favoriteNumbers'); // It also is validated since the value of the key is a valid array
get(person, 'name'); // Error
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgUwE4XDAvDA3gKBvmMAQwFsEAuGAcgEESBLJKgGjwKIHMKYAmAVlYEYAMyIA3EEnpQEAMSQBXaREoBtWnDgAbBC2oB5JETBcqAXUEEA9FZgAVBNDb5REqTIByCkgCNkKmFUARmZeUIBmMxwAXwBuHBwoAE9EGAAlBBIQMQQPcBokIySAaQQkiAAeOwA+DBgAazKQYVx8VWKYejAGpuF7GCIIe3azGAQADxkwABMhhTB6sBAAdzBVUYB+GA7KMAQcpDNKOxH46ITk1PAtJIKigAV-cFLyuoysnLywO6ISssrLghmvAnmBqvEbAQAHobBLCebAKD0NBcKBVaoAClAYCgRC6yGOoUaSUo72yuXyhV+L0qNQAlNhnDAkAgoAokN1sbj8UhVMSzGcEqiMYgUOBQlRXJJpHJFMoqHT4sLRagwBKpe5ct4-CgFUrWSLQRLiGQ9TBIQBRQqSHBAA)

Answer (score 0):

Using `KeysOfType` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64253976/get-all-keys-of-specific-type-from-object-in-typescript) post:

```
type KeysOfType<O, T> = {
  [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends T ? K : never
}[keyof O];
```

We can define `get` as:

```
function get<T = any>() {
    return function <C, Key extends KeysOfType<C, T>>(container: C, key: Key) {
       return container[key];
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
get<string[]>()(person, 'age'); // ERROR - 'age' doesn't point to a string[]
get<string[]>()(person, 'favoriteFruits'); // OKAY
```

Note that currying is required here since [partial type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63678306/typescript-partial-type-inference) is not supported yet.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WY3aEN)