# Type unknown has no call signatures when extracting callable keys from union

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to type a legacy function in our codebase that calls methods on some objects (and applies error handling etc). The partial (toy) solution I have below works for constraining the `action` type, but cannot give an accurate return type (returns `any`).

The `entityGetter` function should take either entityA or entityB, and take only callable keys that begin with `'get'`. This latter part is working correctly, which tells me that getting a correct return value must be possible; but I don't understand why `action` doesn't have the correct type when accessing `entity`.

I have tried assigning defaults to T and A which seem to change nothing.

Is it possible to make this work without any changes to the (runtime) interface of the `entityGetter` function? Ideally with no JS changes at all, but some changes to the body of the function would be permitted.

```
type TEntityA = {
  getA: () => string;
  getB: () => string;
  setC: (arg0: string) => string;
  valD: number;
  getE: () => object;
};
type TEntityB = {
  getA: () => string;
  getB: () => number;
  setC: (arg0: string) => string;
  valD: string;
};
type TEntities = TEntityA | TEntityB;

// type KeysOfType = https://stackoverflow.com/a/64254114

type TGetterKeys<T extends TEntities> = keyof Pick<T, keyof T & (`get${string}`)>;
type TCallableKeys<T extends TEntities> = KeysOfType<T, () => unknown>;
type TGetters<T extends TEntities> = TGetterKeys<T> & TCallableKeys<T>;

const entityGetter = <
  T extends TEntities,
  A extends TGetters<T>
>(action: A, entity: T) => entity[action]();
// This expression is not callable. Type 'unknown' has no call signatures.


const entityA = new EntityA();
const entityB = new EntityB();

const AgetA = entityGetter('getA', entityA); // => string
const BgetB = entityGetter('getB', entityB); // => number

const AgetX = entityGetter('getX', entityA);
// Argument of type '"getX"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"getA" | "getB" | "getE"'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#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-KBNjkR93BfN1mGQIgEDkYALGvJg7jwZCmxbLd0HXZV0BiZEnAoWMtCgb85G-IdCDSRJCO-GxSMkGQhAAfUyBiyKgQxTEof5WPiFwCMYKgcECGhuR4VDn3QkB0gHKIcLiUh8OEKiSO4gRKMYLi6IKRjmNY9jam-CBvxE5DGwXFs0HiDBsAkidWCob9LNI1tejQGguCgE9CJtUzm2ffg0hiGzMzshyBCciT+DcjzJkI7I7FYFCzOfCzSAADUCttbPs+JUvCttXOPSY0EUaxVygAVpm-AAiHKqsA88sncZ8QNvaCa2gYAwLABQ5CsUh7HKvFKpq+SqqgQYRuAfgxomni6qQvAgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS doesn't understand that `T[A]` is always some kind of function. So first we need to persuade it here `(entity[action] as Function)()` to assure it that this is callable. But `ReturnType<Function>` is `any`, so we have to also define the ReturnType for `entityGetter`.

For the same reason as above, a simple `ReturnType<T[A]>` does not work. TS can't predict *(in this generic scenario, before it's called with explicit values and types)* that `T[A]` is callable and so it refuses to do this.
So we have to do this manually: `T[A] extends () => infer R? R: never`. This is now predictable for TS.

I'd also summarize `TGetters`.

```js
type TGetters<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K & `${"get" | "is"}${string}`] extends (...args: any) => any ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

const entityGetter = <
  T extends TEntities,
  A extends TGetters<T>
>(action: A, entity: T): T[A] extends () => infer R ? R : never =>
  (entity[action] as Function)();
```

or

```js
type KeysOfType<T, U> = keyof T & keyof {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends U ? K : never]: 1
};

const entityGetter = <
  T extends TEntities,
  A extends KeysOfType<T, () => unknown> & `${"get" | "is"}${string}`
>(action: A, entity: T): T[A] extends () => infer R ? R : never =>
  (entity[action] as Function)();
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-sG4uwH7ho0mqCd5MCqAIIXBKFQACMMzliuVwADqHVTozUF1RgNEYXZpQlpktvnDobIGbrfbMH90eYZYBCHUADuCDMAiKLopi2JQLiLD4oSUzEoihDuvm3oIL6-o5seQYhmGhr2vSpSxvGSZ8kmabxpmRg0JhoB5hWCBFiWZb0VWdByjSiRaBY0D7iqNHbNC2THmghgcQkXHsDxSp8Wq1S3iAQh7tJh5oEU+T8RqWo0AA5EU2kYWqaBsVA7ytEShC8YeQhVOpaqacEOlVPpR65MZpnMHUQTsBZylQKp5AABq2Vs9nsI5gXOfxRk8CZZxoJYAQ5lA-YXNpGKBWi2myOs-6HsWLDICQCC6KoOjnOoUBgBYuj+OQ8YpXWUBpUUWI4lUrVQU0HXpcA4SZQyhBAA)

**Sidenote:** `T extends TEntities` acts as a guard, preventing you from calling this function with any object that is not `TEntityA | TEntityB` even if follows the general pattern *(object with getter functions starting with `get` or `is`)*. For the typing a simple `T` would suffice.

Comment: Fantastic, I'd have thought that narrowing the type of A to `extends () => unknown` would tell TS enough to know `T[A]` is callable, but this is a sleek solution; thanks so much.

Comment: @jernaumorat I initially also thought so. And if you omit calling `entity[action]` it returns you the correct type of the selected action. But until you call the function and by doing so you pass it some concrete types, `T[A]` could be anything. That's why you get `unknown` and the other mentioned issues.