# Typescript Expands Narrowed Generic Type

Tags: typescript, generics, narrowing

I have this code:

```js
type Constructable = {new(...args: any[]): any, prototype: any}; // Represents a class (that can be called with new)

type WithOnlyType<O, T> = {[P in keyof O as O[P] extends T? P: never]: O[P]}; // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419176/how-to-get-a-subset-of-keyof-t-whose-value-tk-are-callable-functions-in-typ

// Override a constructor with name C in a scope S
function extendConstructor<
    S,
    T extends WithOnlyType<S, Constructable>,
    C extends keyof T>
    (
        className: C, constructor: (...args: ConstructorParameters<T[C]>) => any, scope: S) {

...}
```

However, `ConstructorParameters<T[C]>` is erroring because `Type 'T[C]' does not satisfy the constraint 'abstract new (...args: any) => any'.` Which is odd, because T contains only values that fit that requirement (are `Constructable`) and C is `keyof T`. However, farther down (at the bottom of) the error, I found:

```
Type 'S[string]' is not assignable to type 'abstract new (...args: any) => any'
```

This is true, S could have a lot more values than just classes, however, T is a lot more narrowed than S, and C than string. How to I stop tsc from expanding these types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a design limitation of TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30728](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728) for the description of a similar issue. The compiler is not clever enough to do the sort of higher-order analysis necessary to figure out that `T[C]` will be assignable to `Constructable`, when `T` and `C` are both unspecified generic type parameters.  You wrote `WithOnlyType` specifically to guarantee this sort of constraint, but `WithOnlyType<S, Constructable>[keyof WithOnlyType<S, Constructable>]` is more or less opaque to the compiler.

If you want to work around this, you can use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).  When you have a type `T` that *you* know is assignable to type `U` but the compiler doesn't know this, you can write `Extract<T, U>` instead of `T`.  The compiler sees that `Extract<T, U>` is assignable to `U`, and you know that `Extract<T, U>` will eventually resolve to just whatever `T` is (because `Extract<T, U>` evaluates to any union members of `T` which are assignable to `U`).

So if you change

```
ConstructorParameters<T[C]>
```

to

```
ConstructorParameters<Extract<T[C], Constructable>>
```

the error will go away.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 1):

Typescript won't be ale to follow that that mapped conditional type will result in `T[C]` being a constructable.

You could reframe your type parameters and  make it work:

```
function extendConstructor<
    S extends Record<C, Constructable>,
    C extends keyof WithOnlyType<S, Constructable>>
    (className: C, constructor: (...args: ConstructorParameters<S[C]>) => any, scope: S) {

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGwCGAjAG2gF4oBvBCAdwAoA6BnVAcyQC4ocEQBtAXQCUHLiAA0UMKjjBp4CMO4BfANxQA9GqgAlCJIhIICYEk5RMBHEhM1gACxzAzXKHmiYcBIgBMoVAJZ2UJRUAgBQoaCQUADqAbYA8ggEIAAqcgA88eIpAHxQpGQ8AApQfghQANYQIHAAZlDxnCbxxXxQEAAewIZeJikA-FBFHJQAbhCofBwtRXwq6pq2wMBg7BooOJgVcOOotQRwVHSYcAC2agCO6PrAfohIagCsAIwALM8AnM8A7ABsarZDgBaGRA5gQYBAnBApDoPAGSF1IFVGq1EFAqiAgxA0Yea4gipQ1AQIHuTz4IhA2roBDYO7IIFlEHgcIaBq7VB+LzQHBme5oLAyVC+OJBHCnaAwUrlXlIE5RADKoWptNuiHaXR68GQAuwcFQ6VCUGNUAVGu6CF62ggJ1QXnSMHE2pQGGwFIgOVERpNUs6FqtKLqMTiiWSaUg6QVTv5rtwhA9OW9xpo5ksSAAcuL5LBxCcdbH9Rx6IwWOxYDHBfqikws91UEhIzwYHwcgJ8nkROI5XBIBwFW2yOFFOFQn6tRW9agaAAiHDT8Qqunqmg4AeKY3iQfGnAcVNWchJvn5ytTssusrMARkYfGxRe414XcWffX0KKARAA)

Note: I would suggest putting `scope` first for better code completion on the key.