# how to remove undefined from type to be inferred for useCallback

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-usecallback

New `useCallback` in the react needs to specify args types. I try to specify function type to infer arg type. But if that type contains `undefined`, it can't infer the correct type.

```
  const onDrop: DropzoneOptions['onDrop'] = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
    console.log(acceptedFiles)
  }, []);
  const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive} = useDropzone({onDrop})
```

error:

```
error TS7006: Parameter 'acceptedFiles' implicitly has an 'any' type.

6   const onDrop: DropzoneOptions['onDrop'] = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can add the `Defined` type to fix the problem.

```
type Defined<T> = Exclude<T, undefined>
const onDrop: Defined<DropzoneOptions['onDrop']> = useCallback(/* ... */)
```

Is there any easier way to do this? Maybe proper use of the `!` operator?

Comment: I ended up using the same utility type that you have here. Thanks for the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to `useMemo` hook with the same result and Typescript happiness without additional type.

```
const onDrop  = useMemo(():DropzoneOptions['onDrop']=>acceptedFiles => {
    console.log(acceptedFiles)
  }, []);
  const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive} = useDropzone({onDrop})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [`NonNullable<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) that I think you can use instead of your `Defined`.

You can declare the type `Handler` like this.

```
type Handler<T, K extends keyof T> = NonNullable<T[K]>
```

Here is an example of using it with `useCallback`.

```
const onDropHandler: Handler<DropzoneOptions, 'onDrop'> = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
    /*...*/
}, [])
```

Here is the improved version of type `Handler` declaration that allows only the keys that its type is optional Function. (thanks to [`KeyOfType<T, V>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51419293/430334))

```
type KeyOfType<T, V> = keyof {
    [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V? P: never]: any
}
type Handler<T, K extends KeyOfType<T, Function|undefined>> = NonNullable<T[K]>
```